# Order of the Image of a Matrix in PGL(2,q^n)

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{array}\right)
\in GL(2,q^n)$ is of order $D$ and let $[A]$ denote the image of $A$ in $PGL(2,q^n)$. It is well known that the order of $[A]$ is a divisor of $D$. Now, if $D$ is composite, how can we determine the (exact) order of $[A]$?

As an example, consider $q=2$ and $n=3$ and suppose $A\in GL(2,2^3)$ is of order 9, then what is the order of $[A]$?

In general, what if $D$ is even?

Comment: In your example, the image must have order $9$ too, because the subgroup of scalar matrices has order $7$.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Is there any reference material for the more general question?

Comment: Is it correct then to say that as long as $D \mid (q^n+1)$ but not (q^n-1) since if gcd$(D, q^n-1)$ then $\lambda^D=1$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ implies $\lambda=1$?